# Zip cyclically over multiple lists in Python

Tags: python, zip, python-itertools, cycle

Say I have these three lists:

```
aList = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
bList = ['a','b','c','d']
cList = [1,2]
```

and I want to iterate over them using `zip`.

By using cycle with `zip` as following:

```
from itertools import cycle
for a,b,c in zip(aList, cycle(bList), cycle(cList)):
    print a,b,c
```

I get the result as:

```
1 a 1
2 b 2
3 c 1
4 d 2
5 a 1
6 b 2
```

Though I want my result to be like:

```
1 a 1
2 b 1
3 c 1
4 d 1
5 a 2
6 b 2
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `itertools.repeat()` to repeat the items of third list based on second list:

```
>>> from itertools import repeat, chain
>>> 
>>> zip(aList,cycle(bList), chain.from_iterable(zip(*repeat(cList, len(bList)))))
[(1, 'a', 1),
 (2, 'b', 1),
 (3, 'c', 1),
 (4, 'd', 1),
 (5, 'a', 2),
 (6, 'b', 2)]
```

Comment: I also want to add a dList = [3,4]

Comment: @AbhijayGhildyal If you are using `numpy` you should added the tag to you r question and/or mention a  proper example. I suggest you ask another question since it might has a completely different answer. And you'd get a proper one.

Answer (score 4):

You can apply [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) on `c` and `b` and then restore their original order in the `print` statement:

```
>>> from itertools import product, cycle
>>>
>>> for a, b_c in zip(aList, cycle(product(cList, bList))):
...     print a, b_c[1], b_c[0]
...
1 a 1
2 b 1
3 c 1
4 d 1
5 a 2
6 b 2
```